# Searching through pointer array to count letter uses

Tags: c, pointers

Ok, so I am not looking for an a full answer please. I just don't know where to begin with this. I have a code that is declaring a pointer array full of names. The goal is to write a code to search the names and count each letter that is used.

```
/*                                                                              
 * Search through each character in s,                                          
 * which is array containing n strings,                                         
 * and update the global count array                                            
 * with the correct character counts.                                           
 * Note: check the examples to see                                              
 * if the counts should be case                                                 
 * sensitive or case insensitive.                                               
 */
void letterCount(char * s[], int n){
  //Implement this function                                                     
  int c = 0,x;                      // This is what I've done and I 
  char p = 'a', j = 'z';            // don't know where im messing up.
  while (s[c] != '\0') {            // I know I can't compare pointer
    if (s[c] >= p && s[c] <= j ){   // and integer.
        x = *s[c] - 'a';
          count[x]++;
      }
      c++;
    }
}

/*                                                                              
 * Initialize each value in the global                                          
 * count array to zero.                                                         
 */
void initializeCount(){
  //Implement this function                                                     
  int i;
  for (i = 0; i < 26; i++){      // Also not sure if this is correct.
    count[i] = 0;
  }
}
```

The output should count the letter uses into an array called `count[26]`.
Any suggestions please?

Comment: A string is an array that has 1 or many characters. The length is denoted by the last character with `\0`. That's why at least 1 (if there is only the `\0`-terminator). (For me, it seems you understood this.) What you didn't consider: `s` isn't a string but an **array** of strings. Hence, there must be an outer loop iterating for `s[i]` with i = 0 ... `n` - 1. You have to apply your code to each `s[i]` (which is a `char*` pointing to a string as described at beginning.)

Comment: _"I don't know where im messing up"_ Nor do we because you didn't bother to specify what the problem is. Is there an error? Or does it work but give the wrong results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`s[c]` is not a character, it's a `pointer`, you are comparing `pointer` and character `p` which is not valid,

```
if (s[c] >= p && s[c] <= j ) // here you are comparing address & char, which you shouldn't
```

rotate one more loop for comparing each char of string.

Modify your code as

```
void letterCount(char * s[], int n){
        //Implement this function                                                     
        int c = 0,x,i;                   // This is what I've done and I 
        char p = 'a', j = 'z';            // don't know where im messing up.
       // assuming n is no of string, rotate main loop from 0 to n
        while (c<n) {      
                for(i=0;s[c][i]!='\0';i++)            // I know I can't compare pointer
                        if (s[c][i] >= p && s[c][i] <= j ){   // and integer.
                                x = s[c][i] - 'a';
                                count[x]++;
                        }
                c++;
        }
}
```

I hope you got this.

Comment: `s[c] != '\0'` still looks like a bad idea in the outer while condition, I'd expect `n` to play its role as number of strings in array.

Comment: @grek40 yes true, I didn't observe properly. can rotate loop upto no of strings

Comment: "*s[c] is not a character, it's a string*", not `s[c]` is a pointer, a pointer to `char`, a `char*`. Pointers are not arrays.